# Rectifying compute_curvature.m error in Toolbox Graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently using the Toolbox Graph on the Matlab File Exchange to calculate curvature on 3D surfaces and find them very helpful  (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5355).  However, the following error message is issued in “compute_curvature” for certain surface descriptions and the code fails to run completely:

```
> Error in ==> compute_curvature_mod at 75
> dp = sum( normal(:,E(:,1)) .* normal(:,E(:,2)), 1 );
> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

This happens only sporadically, but there is no obvious reason why the toolbox works perfectly fine for some surfaces and not for others (of a similar topology). I also noticed that someone had asked about this bug back in November 2009 on File Exchange, but that the question had gone unanswered. The post states

> "compute_curvature will generate an error on line 75 ("`dp = sum(
>   normal(:,E(:,1)) .* normal(:,E(:,2)), 1 );`") for SOME surfaces. The
>   error stems from `E` containing indices that are out of range which is
>   caused by line 48 ("`A = sparse(double(i),double(j),s,n,n);`") where `A`'s
>   values eventually entirely make up the `E` matrix. The problem occurs
>   when the `i` and `j` vectors create the same ordered pair twice in which
>   case the sparse function adds the two `s` vector elements together for
>   that matrix location resulting in a value that is too large to be used
>   as an index on line 75. For example, if `i = [1 1]` and `j = [2 2]` and `s
>   = [3 4]` then `A(1,2)` will equal `3 + 4 = 7`.
>
> The `i` and `j` vectors are created here:
>   `i = [face(1,:) face(2,:) face(3,:)];`
>   `j = [face(2,:) face(3,:) face(1,:)];`
>
> Just wanted to add that the error I mentioned is caused by the
>   flipping of the sign of the surface normal of just one face by
>   rearranging the order of the vertices in the face matrix"

I have tried debugging the code myself but have not had any luck. I am wondering if anyone here has solved the problem or could give me insight – I need the code to be sufficiently general-purpose in order to calculate curvature for a variety of surfaces, not just for a select few.

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing the author?  gabriel.peyre 'at' ceremade.dauphine.fr

Comment: I did and am waiting to hear back. However I wanted to hedge my bets on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The November 2009 bug report on File Exchange traces the problem back to the behavior of `sparse`:

> ```
> S = SPARSE(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax) uses the rows of [i,j,s] to generate an
> m-by-n sparse matrix with space allocated for nzmax nonzeros.  The
> two integer index vectors, i and j, and the real or complex entries
> vector, s, all have the same length, nnz, which is the number of
> nonzeros in the resulting sparse matrix S .  Any elements of s 
> which have duplicate values of i and j are added together.
> ```

The lines of code where the problem originates are here:

```
i = [face(1,:) face(2,:) face(3,:)];
j = [face(2,:) face(3,:) face(1,:)];
s = [1:m 1:m 1:m];
A = sparse(i,j,s,n,n);
```

Based on this information removal of the repeat indices, presumably using `unique` or similar, *might* solve the problem:

```
[B,I,J] = unique([i.' j.'],'rows');
i = B(:,1).';
j = B(:,2).';
s = s(I);
```

The full solution may look something like this:

```
i = [face(1,:) face(2,:) face(3,:)];
j = [face(2,:) face(3,:) face(1,:)];
s = [1:m 1:m 1:m];
[B,I,J] = unique([i.' j.'],'rows');
i = B(:,1).';
j = B(:,2).';
s = s(I);
A = sparse(i,j,s,n,n);
```

Since I do not have a detailed understanding of the algorithm it is hard to tell whether the removal of entries will have a negative effect.